# Java HTTPServlet OutputStream not transferring all the data

Tags: java, http, servlets, video-streaming, nio

I have this bit of code in my java servlet, which uses NIO channels to stream video:

```
int bufferSize = 32 * 1024;
os = response.getOutputStream();
in = Channels.newChannel(contentStream);
out = Channels.newChannel(os);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
while (in.read(buffer) > -1 || buffer.position() > 0) {
                endByte += 1;
                buffer.flip();
                out.write(buffer);
                buffer.compact();
                if(endByte == 1830)
                    break;
}
```

If a byte range is requested I will seek using the buffer and then start streaming from the requested start byte.
This is the response     from the Chrome browser

```
GET/Request:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Range:bytes=0-

Response:
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="SampleVideo.mp4"
Content-Length:1055736
Content-Type:video/mp4
```

The above java code is running but on the browser end only 64KB shows as transferred before another request is sent for the remaining bytes:

```
GET/Request:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Range:bytes=1048576-

Response:
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="SampleVideo.mp4"
Content-Length:7160
Content-Range:bytes 1048576-1055735/1055736
Content-Type:video/mp4
```

And in this case the returned data(7KB) does indeed match the amount in the Content-Length. This results in video playback failing and the player shows an error. However if I don't return an ACCEPT-RANGES header the video plays fine, but doesn't allow me to seek to a different part of the video.

This only seems to be an issue for small files <10MB once its around the 30MB range it seems to work fine even though the returned amounts don't match the content-length response value. It'll return around 35MB on the first response sometimes for very large videos <500MB. On Firefox the browser seems to make a lot of small GET requests much more than the Chrome browser does. Not sure why this is happening like this or how I can check how much has/will actually be sent

Answer (score 0):

`read()` doesn't read one byte at a time. So `endByte += 1;` is nonsense. The amount it does read is available as the return value. It should be `endByte += count;` where `count` was the value returned by `read`, if positive, otherwise zero.

Comment: I know that, it's the maximum amount of times the buffer is read, which would be upper bound by 1830 * 32 * 1024 total bytes. My question is why doesn't the browser get what was transmitted, it immediately sends out another GET request without waiting.